# Kernel dies when using pandas to work on dataframe from sql

Tags: python, pandas, kernel

my kernel dies when I try to change a dataframe with data that I get using an sql query.

I reduced the amount of data, increased my RAM and commented out code that consistently crashed the kernel.

```
    python
    import pandas as pd
    import sqlalchemy
    sql_str = """some sql query limit 100""" 
    df = pd.read_sql(sql_str, engine)   
    list=[
    '1st name','2nd name'] 
    for i in range(0,len(list)):
        df.columns.values[i]=list[i]
    #naming the columns of my df
    df=df[df["tradedate"]<'01-01-2017']
    #this is a line of code that sometimes crashes the kernel
    df['strike']=pd.to_numeric(df["strike"],errors='coerce')
    #another one
```

I expect a clean dataframe with which I can work, instead the kernel dies and I get a windows error.

I would be incredibly thankful if somebody could help me here!

Comment: Can you please run the code on Jupyter line by line and let us know which line is causing kernel issues?

Comment: I am doing that, the problem is it is not consistent. Sometimes the whole code runs, sometimes it dies at the first dataframe manipulation, most of the time somewhere in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem, in case somebody randomly finds this questions:

The problem came from the way I named the columns.

```
for i in range(0,len(list)):
      df.columns.values[i]=list[i]
```

does not work. Instead, I use:

```
df.columns=list
```

Now the kernel no longer dies.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use chunksize parameter:

```
df = pd.read_sql(sql_str, engine, chunksize=20) #try different values
```